# How do I make my program work in Windows Vista and Windows 7?

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-7, windows-vista

I have an application written in Delphi 2006 that was working fine in Windows XP. I packed the application using Inno Setup, using Program Files as the default folder. A few users migrated to Windows Vista and Windows 7. The issue here is that the application creates some files inside its installation folder by its own. This was working in XP but in Windows Vista the users were having problems with the created files (they don't appear and so on). After investigating the users' reports I discovered [KB 927387](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927387): "Common file and registry virtualization issues in Windows Vista or in Windows 7."

Running the application with administrator rights just solves the problem, but that is (I think) an awful workaround. I would like to know if there are any directives or tips for making the application compatible with Vista and 7, because more users will migrate to these OS soon.

Comment: What would you do on Windows XP when the user is a standard user?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Vista/Win7, your app can't put the files in a subfolder of Program Files / Programs unless UAC is turned off or the app is running as elevated. Note that "elevated" does not necessarily mean "logged in as Administrator." Non-administrator users can elevate, and Administrator isn't necessarily elevated.

If the app does attempt to write to Program Files but is not elevated, the OS will either block the app or "virtualize" the write (put the files somewhere else), depending upon how UAC is configured. Neither one helps the app succeed at what it was trying to od.

So it needs to put them somewhere else. Where depends on why the files are being created, and you haven't told us that. You can read [this article](http://www.theabsolute.net/sware/delphivista.html#datafolder) to learn about the options. Note that in addition to the user's AppData and Roaming folders, there is also an "All Users" (shared) profile.

You should probably look at [this article and screencast](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33942), which discusses UAC in depth from a Delphi point of view.

Answer (score 13):

You need to re-write your application to store its files in the proper locations, even in XP, but especially in Vista onwards, particularly if UAC is enabled.  This is becoming more and more important to get right as Microsoft keeps locking down and enforcing its security models with each new OS version.  The rules for how to properly manage application- and user-related files is documented on MSDN, for example: ["Application Specification for Microsoft Windows 2000 for Desktop Applications, Chapter 4: Data and Settings Management"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995853.aspx) and ["Application Specification for Microsoft Windows 2000 for Desktop Applications Appendix A: Best Practices"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954149.aspx) (yes, they are old, but are still quite relevant).  Look at SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(), SHGetFolderPath(), SHGetKnownFolderPath() and other related functions to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Files you create for use by your application other than at installation time should go into the ProgramData directory if its global to the workstation, or into the users ApplicationData directory if its specific to the user.

For cases where you absolutely must place a file in the  program files directory, you can use com to request elevation.  [This is discussed in great detail](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2006/09/29/Windows-Vista-for-Developers-_1320_-Part-4-_1320_-User-Account-Control.aspx), and [delphi specific bits are also available](http://pascalfonteneau.developpez.com/articles/delphi/vista/uac/VistaUACandDelphi.pdf).  One example that I have used this is in patching my users installation base.  They are warned by UAC that the system needs to make changes, so if your doing this as an automated task, you might need to rethink the logic to be more user driven.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [another article](http://delphi.about.com/od/kbwinshell/a/SHGetFolderPath.htm), by Zarko Gajic, which shows how to get different system directories.  Also have a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471123/accessing-localapplicationdata-equivalent-in-delphi).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar enquiry [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831810/is-appdata-now-the-correct-place-to-install-user-specific-apps-which-modify-th) (Stack Overflow).

In the end I realised that I needed to put my application into Program Files at install time (requiring UAC/elevation) and then store my app's data in the user's App Data folder. I had to change the way my program generated 'default' configuration settings and also where I was saving this stuff, but it was worth the effort in the end - we ended up with something that installs and runs fine on XP, Vista and Windows 7.

The only UAC hit we get is at installation time, which makes sense to me (and you get a similar hit at install-time on the Mac too). We didn't have any data that would be common to all users in this particular case but I would have looked at the Program Data special folder if that had been the case.

The installer software we use (Setup Factory) made this fairly straightforward (we just wrote a small bit of code to detect XP versus Vista/Win7 and choose the right special folder accordingly). It would be easy to do this in Inno Setup too, from what limited experience I have of it.