# Windows 7 is blocking my application. What should I do?

Tags: delphi

When my application is installed in "C:\Program Files..." in Win7 when I launch it, it can't have access to another executable file in the same directory. Other applications work well with this version of Windows except my app :((
I'm using Delphi 7

Answer (score 2):

There is a really good article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905330.aspx) on developing apps for Windows 7 that addresses UAC issues specifically.

The upshot is, Program Files is regarded as a directory that should not be messed with lightly, Windows 7 wants elevated privileges to access resources from there.

Answer (score 1):

Craig Stuntz typed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002546/how-do-i-make-my-program-work-in-windows-vista-and-windows-7/2002640#2002640) very good like that :

For Vista/Win7, your app can't put the files in a subfolder of Program Files / Programs unless UAC is turned off or the app is running as elevated. Note that "elevated" does not necessarily mean "logged in as Administrator." Non-administrator users can elevate, and Administrator isn't necessarily elevated.

Comment: By default all application started under administrator account are run with standard user privileges unless they ask for elevation. This is true at least for apps started through explorer (ShellExecute). I don't know about CreateProcess but it is probably the same thing.